# SSH GatewayPorts setting only for particular port

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to establish a reverse ssh tunnel with GatewayPorts set to no for all ports apart from a particular port (e.g 2222)

I have tried the following setting in sshd_config

```
Match LocalPort 2222
    GatewayPorts yes
```

I have verified the config using

```
sshd -T -C lport=2222 | grep -i 'gateway'
> gatewayports yes

sshd -T -C lport=3333 | grep -i 'gateway'
> gatewayports no
```

While ports other than 2222 get established with the expected setting, reverse tunnel using port 2222 still binds to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0

The ssh version I am using is

```
ssh -V
> OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Any help regarding this will be much appreciated

Thanks in advance